# QAM modulation problem with python

Tags: python, modulation

I have a IQ signal with a bandwidth of $200\,\text{MHz}$.
I do `I*cos(2*pi*1000e6*t)-Q*sin(2*pi*1000e6*t)`, but my signal doesn't shift to carrier frequency `1000e6` on the power spectrum. I cant find the problem. I do this with Python.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're doing. What's the sampling rate? If you say you have a signal, do you mean baseband or bandpass signal?

Comment: I have baseband signal with sample rate of 250MHz  and its bandwidth is 200MHz. Im trying to upconvert it to carrier frequency. Carrier frequency can be for example 1000MHz. @MarcusMüller

Comment: well, basics question time! What is the maximum frequency you can represent with a sample rate of 250 MHz?

Comment: 125MHz. Okay now i get it haha

Comment: So I need to upsample the baseband I and Q signals for it to work? @MarcusMüller

Comment: see the last sentence of the answer you've gotten :)

Comment: There is no need to simulate it at some actual carrier frequency. Do your simulation with IQ baseband, and then pretend "0" is any other carrier frequency you want. That is what the power spectrum will look like. The actual carrier frequency doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a complex baseband signal (i.e., IQ samples), then you need to multiply that signal by a $cos{(2{\pi}ft/Fs)}$

In python this would look something like this:

```
N  = 1000          # samples in input array
Ts = 1.0 / 250e6   # sample period
f  = 1000e6        # output frequency
t  = np.arange(0, Ts*N, Ts)
y  = x*np.exp(-1j*2*np.pi*f*t)
```

Where `x` is an input array of baseband I/Q samples and `y` is the tuned output.

Keep in mind that if your signal is not sufficiently upsampled, then you won't be able to modulate to the desired output frequency from your question.